# Reversing each word in file and printing it out

Tags: java, string, char

I have a file that looks like it:

> "Gettyburg Address
> Abraham Lincoln
>
> Fourscore and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this
> continent a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the
> proposition that all men are created equal. "

What I am trying to do is to print the file in the same format how it is but with reversed words. Could someone help me with that?

here is my method:

```
public static void convertWord() throws Exception {
    String name;
    int sum = 0;
    
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"));
    while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
        name = sc2.nextLine();
        for (int i = name.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            char c = name.charAt(i);
            System.out.print(c);
            
        }
```

This is the output:
run:
sserddA grubytteGnlocniL maharbA siht no htrof thguorb srehtaf ruo oga sraey neves dna erocsruoF eht ot detacided dna ,ytrebil ni deviecnoc ,noitan wen a tnenitnoc  .lauqe detaerc era nem lla taht noitisoporpBUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Everything is in one line.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse using [`StringBuilder::reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse())

```java
public static void convertWord() throws Exception {
    String name;
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
        name = sc2.nextLine();
        builder.append(name);
    }
    String reverse = builder.reverse().toString();
    System.out.println(reverse);
    sc2.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is more elaborate than just handling the newlines correctly.
The way I understand it is that only the words ***themselves*** need to be reversed, not the ***order*** of the words.

Example: `"Foo bar"` should become `"ooF rab"`, and not `"rab ooF"`.

And then there may be commas, periods, question marks and other stuff that does not belong to a "word", which should also stay in place. Actually this is the far more tricky part of the problem than the word reversing itself.

My first shot would be something like this, although I have not tested it, so don't blame me for minor issues. You get the idea:

```
String[] words = wholeContentsOfFile.split("[\n\t .,!?]"); // whatever delimiters you may like
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String w : words) {
    if (!"".equals(w)) {
        map.put(w, new StringBuilder(w).reverse().toString());
    }
}

String result = s;
for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
    result = result.replaceAll("\\b" + e.getKey() + "\\b", e.getValue());
}

System.out.println(s);
```